# How can I run server-side realtime database queries

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I am using Firebase's Realtime Database.**

I am able to use my old device and permanently keep it on for checking if the host has left a party to therefore notify the users. However, this is inconvenient and there must be a simple server side solution.

I know how to code it (using `.observe` etc.) but I don't know where to run the code. The code will be on a loop to check if a host has left every 10 seconds (this is because the host may run out of battery so the database is not notified). Can I simply run it in functions somehow? Or using hosting?

The server code will send a request to the host, and if there is no response, the party has therefore been closed so it will tell the users.

*Any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.*

---

**If you have any questions, please ask!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was that even if the user left the app, they would still be in the party. I used **user defaults** so it can remember if the user *was* in a party so it can return them.

I also used **[Realtime Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)** which can remove all information about a user with one action in the app (so **all** data gets removed, and not left behind, which would create a waste of unusable database memory).

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to the iOS. Put your initial code into the `viewDidLoad` or `init` methods (depends on how do you write the code) and forget about it. Those methods are called once per an instance. For now Firebase works fine on your usecase. At least I don't have any wierd updates on the `observe` method. also you can specify what do you want to observe exactly in the Firebase (something like the `new` or `last 15`)

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question. I can't rely on **ANY** code in the app to make sure I know if the host is disconnected. This is why I want a server to check if the host will still respond.

Comment: as far as I know, firebase doesn't support that behaviour by default. you need to make an explicit tag in the database to identify the online presence and manage it properly on any platform. Something like: UserIsDisconnected: Bool in the database and proper handling when he goes online or offline on his client. Since Firebase is "backendless" all involved platforms have to manage it separately. After that you can use `observe` to subscribe to the host's online flag in the firebase. Sorry, I've really missunderstood your question

Comment: Since I can't really do that, I think I will stick to having a device constantly running for now.

Comment: Please provide the question with the code you use to check the host `online` status right now. Maybe there is another solution to your issue.

Comment: Currently I don't have code to check the host's online status. But I'm just planning for the future, and so I'm not so sure right now. For my host to log out if the app enters the background, I will use `.removeValue()`

Comment: It depends on your real usecases then. However in your case you have to do it explicitly. Something like a combination of ```.child("party_id").child("host_online")``` flag for the party and applicationWillEnterBackground / applicationDidEnterForeground for the host